# JS (jQuery) function with empty body

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, debugging

I have a function in the code that wasn't written by me.

```
$("*").not("a, li, ul").click('click', function(){})
```

This function replaces event listeners on empty string or what?
What is the purpose of making functions with empty body. Is any other way to write things clear?

Comment: This will just do nothing. It will not replace, it would add - an empty listener.

Comment: @axel.michel thank you, you wrote exactly what I mean writing that its replacing something. Do you know the purpose of adding empty listeners?

Comment: @ciprianoss is it true that if there were some event listeners before function execution? that they will be replaced(deleted)?

Comment: @ciprianoss that's not true - plain javascript `element.onclick()` would do that, but not jQuery

Comment: @baao you are right, i totally forgot about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does nothing. It doesn't add something, nor does it remove something. It's just wasted internet traffic bytes because more data has to be downloaded by the client. See below, it still executes all:

```js
$('#a').click(function() {alert("foo")});
$('#a').click(function() {});
$('#a').click(function() {});
$('#a').click(function() {});
$('#a').click(function() {});
$('#a').click(function() {alert("bar")})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
a
</div>
```

There's no purpose of adding empty listeners what so ever.

Comment: It also waste of time on debuging. It stops debuger very often(